# Salesforce Rest API call from typescript using axios

Tags: axios, salesforce, soql, rest

I am trying to fetch records from a scratch org using the tooling API provided by salesforce and user access token. Lets say

```
accesstoken = "abcd"
url = "https://example.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+Account"
```

I have used axios node module to make the API call as given below

```
    const options = {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    axios.get(url, options).then(response => {
        console.log(response.status);
        if(response.status == 200){
            console.log(response.data);
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
   });
```

The call responds with a status 200 i.e the request provided a response. But instead of correct records from Account object, I get the login html page

> ' Login | Salesforcehtml{visibility:
> hidden;}a{color:#0070d2;}body{background-color:#F4F6F9;}#content,.container{background-color:#ffffff;}#header{color:#16325c;}body{display:
> table;
> width:100%;}#content{margin-bottom:24px;}#wrap{height:100%;} html { visibility: hidden; } if (self == top)
> {document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'visible';} else
> {document.write = ''; top.location = self.location;
> setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML='';},
> 1);window.self.onload=function(evt){document.body.innerHTML='';};}var
> SFDCSessionVars={"server":"https://test.salesforce.com/login/sessionserver212.html","im":true,"ah":"active","save":"Save","saveOne":"Save
> 1 Change","sum":"#p# Saved Usernames","iaac":false,"hac":"Choose a
> Username","suo":"1 Saved Username","title":" |
> Salesforce","saveMany":"Save #p#
> Changes","lpt":"Login","lllbl":"Lightning
> Login","host":"test.salesforce.com","le":false,"heu":"Edit Username
> List","ic":false,"lh":false,"ur":"https://business-data-8148-dev-ed.cs79.my.salesforce.com","hidp":"Log
> In Using","ih":"inactive","dc":"Username removed. Click Save to Commit
> Changes."};LoginHint.hideLoginForm();Edit ListSaveCancel
>
> UsernamePassword Caps Lock is on.Remember
> me
> Forgot Your
> Password?To go to your company's login
> page, enter the custom domain name.
>
> Custom Domainhttps://*domain*.my.salesforce.comContinueBackLog In with a Different
> Username© 2020
> salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.<iframe frameborder="0" src="/s.gif" id="marketing"
> name="marketing" scrolling="no" title="Marketing"
> tabindex="-1"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups
> allow-same-origin allow-scripts" >LoginLoginHint.getSavedIdentities(false);function
> handleLogin(){document.login.un.value=document.login.username.value;document.login.width.value=screen.width;document.login.height.value=screen.height;document.getElementById("Login").disabled=true;document.getElementById("login_form").submit();}function
> lazyload(){document.getElementById("pwcapsicon").src="/img/icon/capslock_blue.png";document.getElementById("marketing").src="https://c.salesforce.com/login-messages/promos.html";}loader();
>
> '

Does anyone know what am I missing in here? According to salesforce documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm
the accessToken in the header should be enough to make the API call.

Note: I gained the access token by running

```
sfdx force:user:display -u <username>
```

Comment: Can you point to the docs where you can get an access token using that command?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_user.htm#cli_reference_force_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your query is wrong. You selected Tooling API service which is for metadata (info about classes, triggers, objects, fields, deployments, running unit tests...). If you want to query Accounts - that's normal data. Try just `/services/data/v49.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+Account`

[image]

2. I don't think you need `Content-Type` header in there. You don't POST anything. At best you can send `Accept` (`application/json`, `application/xml`)
3. Are you sure the session id was valid? As in you could go to the org, Setup -> Session management, see it there? Or in the user's login history?
4. It might be that your SF admin did something nasty like locking sessions down to IP from which they originated or maybe the user doesn't have API access... See if you can create your call in [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) -> Utilities -> REST Explorer first, then go back to Axios?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it all and they are all good. But I am still getting the login page in response.

Comment: Is there a way to see details of the network traffic? I don't know Axios but something like Chrome or Firefox's dev tools and Network tab. You probably are getting a HTTP 301/302 redirect and the url of the login page you end up on might have some error text in it. Something "thinks" it's normal web access, not api access. It's stupid but can you try setting a cookie header too? bit like https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7584/799. Cookie is not needed in API calls but it helps if you want to screenscrape the SF internal pages for example...

Comment: I figured out the problem. Your suggestions were helpful. I later found out that there was a problem in my logic that was sending incorrect url for query;